# OpenAPI generator typescript-axios changes property name, and can't pass dates as strings

Tags: typescript, axios, openapi, openapi-generator

I'm doing code generation with the open api generator tool to generate a `typescript-axios` client, but unfortunately there's a couple of issues I'm running into.

1. There is a property in the open api doc we're generating from called `long`.  However, the interface it generates changes that property to `_long` which is not correct.  I can't find anywhere in the mustache template that is doing this so it must be happening in the CLI layer.  Can this behavior be prevented?

Swagger property definition:

```
"long": {
  "type": "number",
  "description": "The longitude location.",
  "format": "double",
  "nullable": true
}
```

Codegen interface property output:

```
/**
 * The longitude location.
 * @type {number}
 * @memberof ...
 */
_long?: number | null;
```

2. Dates are passed as strings to the API and are defined as such in the open api doc, but it seems when they have a `date-time` format, the interface says it requires a `Date` object.  This is not ideal in our situation, but again this appears to happen at the CLI level so I can't prevent this behavior by modifying the mustache template.

Swagger property definition:

```
"startDate": {
  "type": "string",
  "description": "Gets or sets the start date of the search date range.",
  "format": "date-time",
  "nullable": true
},
```

Codegen interface property output:

```
/**
 * Gets or sets the start date of the search date range.
 * @type {Date}
 * @memberof ...
 */
startDate?: Date | null;
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Please open an issue via https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/issues/new so that the community can help you out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass a `type-mappings` to the CLI:

`java -jar openapi-generator-4.2.3.jar generate --type-mappings DateTime=string` etc..

This will turn the type `Date` into a string. Problem is that it doesn't matter if you define a `date` or a `date-time` in your schema definition. You will get only `string` now.